# SQL: Difference in amounts between rows and columns

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a Table 
With the below data

```
Table X             
Seq_no    A    Claim    Payment     Balance (to be calculated)
1        abc    100     10          90 (100-10)
2        abc            50          40 (90-50)
3        abc            20          20 (40-20)
1        xyz    150     10          140 (150-10)
1        qwe    200     10          190 (200-10)
```

I need to calculate the column Balance.

I am trying with the below Query
SQL >

```
Select
Seq_no, a, Claim, Payment, 
CASE 
    When Seq_no =1
    then (claim-Payment) 
    Else ( lag(Balance)- Payment over (order by Balance))
END as  Balance
from table X
```

However i am getting a error

```
ORA-00904: "Balance": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

I believe this is because Balance is not an existing column name.

Is there a correct way to achieve the results.?

***Update:***
***I missed an important part. ***

The data i have is in the below format:

```
Table X             
Seq_no    A    Claim    Payment    
1        abc    100     10         
2        abc    100     50         
3        abc    100     20         
1        xyz    150     10          
1        qwe    200     10
```

I need the results in the below format.

```
Table X             
Seq_no    A    Claim    Payment     Balance (to be calculated)
1        abc    100     10          90 (100-10)
2        abc            50          40 (90-50)
3        abc            20          20 (40-20)
1        xyz    150     10          140 (150-10)
1        qwe    200     10          190 (200-10)
```

The Seq_no calculation has been done to make the claim column null for the cases of duplicate claims, which i had figured out already.

Comment: You forgot to add other **RDBMS** tags like `postgresql`, `db2` etc.

Comment: `ORA` error clearly indicates your database is `oracle`. Why did you tag `mysql` and `sql-server`?

Comment: @Jerry - Please accept the answer which best suits your purpose by clicking the `tick` symbol on left of the answer, so the question can be closed. Cheers.

Comment: @LalitKumarB my Bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reference balance before create it.

You can use a "running sum" for what you want to achieve.

Notice that I partitioned by A because you want another balance for every A.

```
Select
    Seq_no, a, Claim, Payment, 
    sum(nvl(claim,0) - payment) over (partition by A order by seq_no) as Balance
from X;
```

Result:

```
SEQ_NO  A   CLAIM   PAYMENT BALANCE
1       abc 100     10      90
2       abc         50      40
3       abc         20      20
1       qwe 200     10      190
1       xyz 150     10      140
```

**EDIT:** With newer dataset you just need to replace nvl function with a case when seq=1:

```
Select
    Seq_no, 
    a, 
    case when seq_no=1 then claim else 0 end as Claim, 
    Payment, 
    sum(case when seq_no=1 then claim else 0 end - payment) 
          over (partition by A order by seq_no) as Balance
from X;
```

Comment: Excellent use to `sum over partition by`. +1

Comment: This is great help Florin. as the data i have is already a result of a complex query.

Comment: Unfortunately, i forgot to give the exact data that i have, the claim column doesn't have null values for all A's. I have made an update to my Original post.

Comment: Select
    Seq_no, a, Claim, Payment, 
    sum(nvl(claim,0) - nvl(payment,0)) over (partition by A order by seq_no) - Claim*(seq_no-1) as Balance
from X;  helped resolve

Comment: It is easier(with sample data - I don't know your data/tables). See my update :)

Answer (score 2):

In order to use `balance` as a column identifier, you must go one level deep, i.e. make your existing query as a **sub-query**.

**Working demo:**

```
SQL> WITH sample_data AS(
  2  SELECT 1 Seq_no, 'abc' A, 100 Claim, 10 Payment FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 2 Seq_no, 'abc' A, NULL Claim, 50 FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 3 Seq_no, 'abc' A, NULL Claim, 20 FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 1 Seq_no, 'xyz' A, 150 Claim, 10 FROM dual UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 1 Seq_no, 'qwe' A, 200 Claim, 10 FROM dual
  7  )
  8  -- end of sample_data mimicking real table
  9  SELECT seq_no, A, claim, payment,
 10    CASE
 11      WHEN lag(balance) OVER(PARTITION BY A ORDER BY seq_no) IS NULL
 12      THEN balance
 13      ELSE lag(balance) OVER(PARTITION BY A ORDER BY seq_no) - payment
 14    END balance
 15  FROM
 16    (SELECT seq_no, A, claim, payment,
 17      CASE
 18        WHEN seq_no = 1
 19        THEN claim     - payment
 20        ELSE lag(claim - payment) OVER(PARTITION BY A ORDER BY seq_no) - payment
 21      END balance
 22    FROM sample_data
 23    );

    SEQ_NO A        CLAIM    PAYMENT    BALANCE
---------- --- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 abc        100         10         90
         2 abc                    50         40
         3 abc                    20         20
         1 qwe        200         10        190
         1 xyz        150         10        140

SQL>
```

**UPDATE** : If you not-null values always for `claim`, then you could do a running diff:

```
SQL> WITH sample_data AS(
  2    SELECT 1 Seq_no, 'abc' A, 100 Claim, 10 Payment FROM dual UNION ALL
  3    SELECT 2 Seq_no, 'abc' A, 100 Claim, 50 FROM dual UNION ALL
  4    SELECT 3 Seq_no, 'abc' A, 100 Claim, 20 FROM dual UNION ALL
  5    SELECT 4 Seq_no, 'abc' A, 100 Claim, 10 FROM dual UNION ALL
  6    SELECT 5 Seq_no, 'abc' A, 100 Claim, 10 FROM dual UNION ALL
  7    SELECT 1 Seq_no, 'xyz' A, 150 Claim, 10 FROM dual UNION ALL
  8    SELECT 1 Seq_no, 'qwe' A, 200 Claim, 10 FROM dual
  9    )
 10  -- end of sample_data mimicking real table
 11  SELECT Seq_no,
 12    a,
 13    Claim,
 14    Payment,
 15    CASE
 16      WHEN seq_no = 1
 17      THEN claim     - payment
 18      ELSE SUM(claim - payment) over (partition BY A order by seq_no) - claim*(seq_no-1)
 19    END balance
 20  FROM sample_data;

    SEQ_NO A        CLAIM    PAYMENT    BALANCE
---------- --- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 abc        100         10         90
         2 abc        100         50         40
         3 abc        100         20         20
         4 abc        100         10         10
         5 abc        100         10          0
         1 qwe        200         10        190
         1 xyz        150         10        140

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: You Sir deserve an Oscar.

Comment: The OP induced with that case on `When Seq_no =1` a too complicated and not needed discussion on null and lags and so on... See my response, it is more simple.

Comment: My apologies for providing incorrect data.I have updated my Original post.
Seq_no is calculated from another sub-query to make duplicate claim amounts Null.

Comment: @Lalit Thanks for the answer.
However the above logic fails if there are data with seq no >3 ( 4,5 etc)
Say:
WITH sample_data AS(
   SELECT 1 Seq_no, 'abc' A, 100 Claim, 10 Payment FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 2 Seq_no, 'abc' A, NULL Claim, 50 FROM dual UNION ALL
   SELECT 3 Seq_no, 'abc' A, NULL Claim, 20 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 Seq_no, 'abc' A, Null Claim, 10 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 Seq_no, 'abc' A, Null Claim, 10 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 Seq_no, 'xyz' A, 150 Claim, 10 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 Seq_no, 'qwe' A, 200 Claim, 10 FROM dual
    )

Comment: @jerry Ok, no problem. See the updated answer. It should work for any number of seq_no.

Comment: @FlorinGhita Yeah correct. The `NULLs` could be handled easily without `CASE` as you have shown.

Answer (score -1):

You are correct that the error occurs because Balance is not a column in your table.  You need to add that column.

The bigger problem is that unfortunately it's not possible to compute a running total using a single SQL statement the way you are trying to do it.  SQL is not well suited to an operation like this.  It can be done in a stored procedure using a cursor but the end result is procedural and not set-based, thus performance would be poor.  Here's how to do it in SQL Server (as an example, not tested):

```
DECLARE PaymentCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT A, Claim, Payment FROM X ORDER BY A, Seq_no
OPEN PaymentCursor

DECLARE @A VARCHAR(16)
DECLARE @Claim MONEY
DECLARE @Payment MONEY
DECLARE @Balance MONEY
DECLARE @PreviousA VARCHAR(16)

SET @PreviousA = ''

FETCH NEXT FROM PaymentCursor INTO @A, @Claim, @Payment
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF @A <> @PreviousA
    BEGIN
        SET @Balance = 0
        SET @PreviousA = @A
    END

    SET @Balance = @Balance + @Claim - @Payment

    UPDATE X SET Balance = @Balance WHERE CURRENT OF PaymentCursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM PaymentCursor INTO @A, @Claim, @Payment
END

CLOSE PaymentCursor
DEALLOCATE PaymentCursor
```

If your application really needs to know the account balance associated with each transaction, the better approach is to compute the balance each time a row is inserted.  Wrap the insertion logic in a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertAndComputeBalance
    @A VARCHAR(16),
    @Claim MONEY,
    @Payment MONEY
AS
    DECLARE @MAX_Seq_no INTEGER = (SELECT MAX(Seq_no) FROM X WHERE A = @A)

    INSERT INTO X
    SELECT @MAX_Seq_no + 1, @A, @Claim, @Payment, Balance + @Claim - @Payment FROM X
    WHERE A = @A AND Seq_no = @MAX_Seq_no
```

In theory you could call similar logic from a trigger so that it is automatically executed each time a row is inserted, but triggers can be evil so proceed very carefully with that approach.